# Display 2 values in a WPF DataGridComboBoxColumn DisplayMemberPath

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have a series of objects representing some data points listed in a DataGridComboBoxColumn.  Setting the DisplayMemeberPath property I can display a single value, say the x coordinate.  What I would like to do though is display both the x and y coordinates in 'x, y' format.  Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not use DisplayMemberPath, but instead use a DataTemplate, and a TemplateColumn

```
    <ComboBox>
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding First}" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Second}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```